# Highcharts line chart not rendering on IE 11

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having compatibility issue with highcharts line chart . It works fine on `IE10` but on `IE11`  it doesn't display the chart on the page.

My jsfiddle works on `IE11` but it doesn't work when I run the same code in my main project. And also I m not getting any error

I involed `<meta tag` for `IE11` and `Edge` in my master page  , still shows same issue

Any help appreciated.

[Jsfiddle provided here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/)

Comment: Your jsFiddle has some errors in it. Hit the JSHint button on your fiddle ans scroll down to the red dots. You have extra semicolons in several places. Maybe IE11 was trying to be too strict (I know it hates dangling commas).

Comment: I fixed the errors . I ll check it again in my main project. Thanks

Comment: Looks different between Chrome and IE. But I am not sure what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: I just need to see the lines on the chart . processing , completed and also tooltips when you hove over. if these is fine , it is ok for me

Comment: here is the new one  http://jsfiddle.net/za4y9aaq/23/

Comment: So at this moment what is wrong?